# PowerBI - Time Lag Calculation in Dates, using Query Editor

Tags: powerbi

I'm new to Power BI Desktop, coming from Excel.

In the query editor, I would like to create a new column in a table with the difference in time/date from one record to the next, by a separate grouping column (device). An example explains it better. Here's the starting point for the data, with one column for the device id, and another for the Date of the event.

```
Device   Date  
A        5/1/2016  
B        5/1/2016  
C        5/2/2016  
A        5/4/2016  
B        5/5/2016  
A        5/10/2016  
B        5/9/2016  
C        5/12/2016
```

I would like to group by Device and Sort by Date, then calculate the differences, to make something like this:

```
Device   Date       Lag   
A        5/1/2016   (null)   
A        5/4/2016   3  
A        5/10/2016  6  
B        5/1/2016   (null)  
B        5/5/2016   4  
B        5/9/2016   4  
C        5/2/2016   (null)  
C        5/12/2016  10
```

What's the best way to do this in Power BI query editor?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The info is helpful, but I'm getting an issue with datediff throwing an error, "start date cannot be greater than end date". The other example worked (the account key example) - thank-you! But because I'm working in dates, the output is a date, and I would like it to be an integer. How do I cast from date to integer? PS. The references were also very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution. But it does not involve Query editing.

we're gonna create a calculated column and do it the dax way.

> 1) In your Fields pane, right click on the table and Select "New
>   Column"
>
> 2) In the formula bar, type in the formula below. replace TableName with your table name

```
    LagColumn = DATEDIFF(TableName[Date]
                , CALCULATE(MAX(TableName[Date]), 
                    FILTER(TableName, 
                        TableName[Device] = EARLIER(TableName[Device]) && 
                        TableName[Date] < EARLIER(TableName[Date])
                    )
                )
            , DAY
            )
```

> 3) Select Device, Date and the LagColumn in your report now. Choose "Table" option from the visualization panel.

**Explanation of the formula -**

1) The new lagColumn is the DATEDIFF in days of two entities.

2) First argument is the DATE field of the current row

3) Second argument is the **maximum** date value of all the dates that are **less than the current row's date** and that **belongs to the same device** as the current row. (EARLIER helps you retrieve the value of the current row in the previous context.)

read more here

1) EARLIER - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634551.aspx

2) Row Context and Filter Context - https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/row-context-and-filter-context-in-dax/

Screenshot of a similar use-case:

[image]

Here,

- AccountAlternateKey corresponds to Date
- ParentAccountAlternateKey
  corresponds to Device, and
- LagColumn is LagColumn

**Note -** For every group, lag of the first column is the first column itself. If you want it to be NULL, you can check if ISBLANK(CALCULATE....) is true and then make it null. that just adds a little bit complexity to the formula..

Proposing DAX solution since i don't think there is a query way to deal with this, AFAIK.

Let me know if you have any more questions..