# Time Lag Calculation in Dates/Datetime by using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am trying to reproduce this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37446950/powerbi-time-lag-calculation-in-dates-using-query-editor). I use this DAX expression

```
LagColumn = DATEDIFF(
            CALCULATE(MAX(MyTable[Date]), 
                FILTER(MyTable, 
                    MyTable[Device] = EARLIER(MyTable[Device]) && 
                    MyTable[Date] < EARLIER(MyTable[Date])
                )
            ), MyTable[Date]

        , DAY
        )
```

However, this calculation does not work when you have two same values (I modified the input of the example):

[image]

It should be 0 instead of 3. How can I solve this problem? It seems that there is no Lag function in DAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyTable[Date] < EARLIER(MyTable[Date])` condition is looking for rows with the Date column values **before** the Date value it's currently iterating over. So when the engine is at row 3, the FILTER function will still (just like it did at row 2) leave only the first row.

Not sure about the particularities of your application, but if it's some sort of a log, you can simply add an index column and use it in your FILTER function:

```
LagColumn = DATEDIFF(
            CALCULATE(MAX('MyTable'[Date]), 
                FILTER('MyTable', 
                    'MyTable'[Device] = EARLIER('MyTable'[Device]) && 
                    'MyTable'[EntryIndex] < EARLIER ('MyTable'[EntryIndex])
                )
            ),'MyTable'[Date]

    , DAY
    )
```

Comment: glad to hear that :)